# Как из активити в адаптер можно передать bundle?

Tags: java, android, android-bundle

Нужно передать строку из активити в адаптер, насколько я знаю нужно передать это в bundle, но как не знаю. Помогите справиться с задачей.

Comment: тогда разрешите уточнить что вы понимаете под adapter, то есть ощущение, что вы пишите о другой вещи.

Comment: Есть активити А в котором есть метод для выставления даты makeDate(), нужно эту дату передать в адаптер и в нем в методе getView() получить время переданное из активити

Comment: тогда сделайте свой адаптер наследуясь от одного из стандартных, сделайте внутри переменную private Date date; и 
pulic void setDate(Date date){
  this.date = date
}

А в activity используйте этот метод. Он будет менять переменную date, а метод getView(), использовавший её, будет брать уже изменённую переменную.

Если помог сообщите пожалуйста.

Comment: попробую сейчас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В адаптер можно передать данные через конструктор, сделав свой адаптер, переопределив стандартный адаптер. И не обязательно это делать через `Bundle`

Comment: а как можно это еще сделать?

Comment: @java сделайте интерфейс и дергайте методы интерфейса.